# Using YouTube API to list documentary videos uploaded from NZ

Tags: youtube-api

I am helping a researcher wanting to list YouTube videos uploaded from a specific country/region that are a particular genre.
In particular, documentary videos uploaded by people from New Zealand. My expectation based on what I have found in Stack Overflow is that the region is more about access to the video rather than the region it was uploaded from but if someone knows a workaround that could return that list via the api that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like this:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=50&location=42.0000,174.0000&location-radius=1000km

This search searches for:

- 50 Videos
- All from New Zealand
- Within a 1000KM ratius of the center of it

  And For videos over the first 50 just use=
  http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=50&start-index=50&location=42.0000,174.0000&location-radius=1000km

  And Change the "start-index" to be at increments of 50...

  So 50, 100, 150, 200...

---

**But Beware im preatty sure this only works if the author chooses to put a location on their video.**